# How to create a similar 2.5D art style character

Tags: 2d, graphics, art, 2.5d

EDIT: I am asking about the characters not the 2.5 scene

I am the graphic designer of a game and I want to recreate the look and feel of these images:

[image]

[image]

My questions are:

1. Does this style have a specific name?
2. Can you link me to tutorials for this game style?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How are "2.5D" art assets created?](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/27577/how-are-2-5d-art-assets-created)

Comment: Not really :) I am asking about the characters not the 2.5 style

Comment: Are the characters not part of the 2.5d style?

Comment: Of course they are, but I was talking about this kind of drawing: Characters without legs and arms, what are they called? I was also looking for the tutorials

Comment: maybe you should ask this on http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for your first question, do you mean Weebles? Matryoshka dolls?  Have you heard it called something before?  I can't seem to pinpoint a certain term, but perhaps you can be the first to call it something!

The shading is basically a gradient of darker values toward the bottom of each major part of the character (body and head) and lighter toward the top.

As for the general style, seems like Hello Kitty anime, with a big head and small body.  Maybe a form of [Chibi Animation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_deformed)?

What came up in a 5-minute google search:

http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/InvisibleAnatomy

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_deformed

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Fr4_0YHrA4

Again, probably a question for a graphical art stacks exchange hub.